# Parser tokens like those in PHP in other languages?

Tags: java, php, c++, ruby, token

Short version:

Is there something similar to [PHP parser tokens](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php) in other interpreted languages (Python, Ruby, etc.) and compiled languages (the C family, Java, etc.)?

Long Version:

On [the CPP Rocks website](http://cpprocks.com/) there is [an article showing a visual comparison of language complexity](http://cpprocks.com/cpp-ruby-coffeescript-language-complexity/) by means of a graph that breaks down the various building blocks of a language into categories. The graph for Coffeescript looks like this:

[image]

I wanted to make such a graph for PHP using [the parser tokens](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php) as a starting point (to make sure I don't miss anything and because I'm lazy). I was wondering if there is something similar to these tokens in other in other interpreted languages (Python, Ruby, etc.) and compiled languages (the C family, Java, etc.).

Findings thus far:

- Java: the Chapters of the Language Specification describing [Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html) and  [Lexical Structure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html) seem a good place to start.
- Python: Chapter 2 of the manual does describe [Python's lexical structure](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html).
- Ruby: [the token list for Ruby](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/irb/ruby-token.rb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All parsers make the input into tokens. The language may or may not show what those tokens are, and of course, the actual meaning and names of tokens vary, and of course, since different languages have different syntax, set of reserved words and other constructs, each language will have a slightly different set of tokens.

A token here is just a "named representation of the actual symbol in the language specification". So for example, the parser will see the word `break` as input, and make it into the token `T_BREAK`.

For the type of graph you are looking at, you need to know what the different language constructs are, categorise and then show them graphically - I'm not sure looking at the list of tokens is the best way to achieve that.

Comment: I was thinking of using something like a token list (for languages I  am less familiar with) to have a way of finding out what/how many language constructs there are. I am also uncertain if this is the *best* way of doing this but I can really think of another way except doing extensive research into each language I would like to graph.
--
Of course, the token list would just be a starting point, I would still need to categorise it by hand.

Answer (score -1):

There is no such thing as a list of tokens for a language. Tokens are a property of the parser (more precisely: they are a property of the interface between the lexer and the parser), not the language. A different parser parsing the same language may use a completely different set of tokens. Many modern parsers are lexerless which means they don't have tokens *at all*.

In Ruby, for example, Melbourne (the parser used by Rubinius) uses a very different set of tokens than RedParse/RubyLexer (used by all sorts of projects) which again uses a very different set of tokens than the ANTLR-based parser used by XRuby and Sapphire in Steel.

Comment: Maybe my terminology is wrong, I'll try to fix that. (Suggestions are welcome). what I'm trying to find, for Interpreted languages, is a list of things the interpreter know/looks for and for Compiled languages things the compiler looks for. In PHP they are documented in as Tokens. I don't know how/what they are or are called in other languages, hence my question.